# doing something on second monitor makes fullscreen app invisible

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I am having an issue, because whenever I have a fullscreen app on the primary monitor, in my case, Minecraft, and I go over to switch podcasts, my Minecraft goes invisible until I click back over. Why is this, and is there a setting I can switch to make fullscreen apps persist being open on a monitor?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Is Minecraft running at native resolution on that screen? Is the OS and the video drivers fully updated?

Comment: I just thought this is normal behavior. A full screen app is just that. It consumes your entire screen. If it happens to be sitting on only one monitor it’s going to go in to the background when you access something outside of that monitor because it’s all part of the same screen.